# will_paginate - Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, will-paginate

I'm trying to paginate an Association but i'm missing something.

This is where i need the pagination with `.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)`. If i understood correctly i have to make a variable in my controller to fetch the towns ?

```
<% @alliance.players.each do |p| %>
  <% p.towns.each do |t| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What i'm calling:

```
Alliance ->
  Players ->
    Towns <--
```

**Basically i'm stuck on how to paginate the Association in a 2nd level loop.**

Maybe there is a better way of doing this.

---

The associations:

```
class Alliance < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Primary Key
  self.primary_key = 'grepo_id'

  # Associations
  has_many :players
end


class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Primary Key
  self.primary_key = 'grepo_id'

  # Associations
  has_many :towns
  belongs_to :alliance    
end

class Town < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Primary Key
  self.primary_key = 'grepo_id'

  # Associations
  belongs_to :player, :foreign_key => :player_id
end
```

I've tried and read a lot but haven't found any solution.

I tried to make a variable in my Controller:

```
@alliance_towns = @alliance.players.towns.order("rank ASC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
```

so i can call `@alliance_towns.each do {}` but on this i'm getting

```
undefined method `towns' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Player:0x007f9268d91348>
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Did you get any error? And also you have `@alliances` in the `index action` and `@alliance` in the `view code`.Is that a typo?

Comment: The view is for the show action. Oh i tried so much, but i think i'm doing this completely wrong.

Comment: Can you post your show action?

Comment: Doesn't contain anything yet. I'm calling the association @alliance.players. I tried making a variable in the controller which i will edit in my question now.

Comment: It is better posting your full controller code as it is.

Comment: A player has many shows, so `player.shows` would work, but you're trying to use `players.shows`, which obviously doesn't work. You can probably solve it by using `joins`, but your question doesn't have enough information to answer it.

Comment: @Pavan the controller is practically empty, there is nothing related to this in the controller:) @ Misha, Let me update my Question with more Information.

Comment: Edited my Question. That's all the info.

Comment: No it's not. Where does `@alliance` come from?

Comment: We are in the Alliance/Show view. @alliance = Alliance.find(params[:id])

Comment: Ok.Then as @Mischa said try it like this `@alliance_towns = @alliance.player.towns.order("rank ASC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)` notice the singular `player`.

Comment: @Pavan, no that's not correct. He should use a join.

Comment: @Pavan undefined method `player' for Alliance. A Alliance has_many :players.

Comment: @Mischa Opps!I thought it is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a [join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables). Something like this:

```
@alliance_towns = Town.joins(:player).where('players.alliance_id = ?', params[:id]).order('rank ASC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
```

Comment: As Always.. a huge THANK YOU :)